# How to create a Poincaré disk type kaleidoscope in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request

Creating a kaleidoscope in *Mathematica* is not a new topic at all, examples can be found from the links like [Wolfram reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/UseGeometricTransformationsToCreateAKaleidoscope.html) and [Wolfram demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Kaleidoscope/).

My question is how to create Poincaré disk type of kaleidoscopes in *Mathematica* like the guys do in Java. Any idea and suggestion would be gratefully appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 30):

Hyperbolic lines in the Poincare disk are arcs of circles which, if extended,
would meet the unit circle boundary orthogonally. Tiling the disk requires
reflection of a tile's vertices and circular edges in those same circular
edges. This corresponds to inversion in a circle.

Begin with a central polygon having p edges, with q such polygons meeting
at each vertex. Then reflect this polygon in each of its circular edges to
form p new polygons. Nest this iteration to the depth required.

Here is some code (perhaps too much). With these basics you can add variations
like colouring hyperbolic polygons (not straight-edged polygons), or marking
tiles with lines at the midpoints (forming the dual tiling), or extending to 3D,
or truncating the tile corners to form additional shapes.

The function HyperbolicLine draws hyperbolic lines between points P and Q in the Poincare disk.

```
HyperbolicLine[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] :=
   If[N[Chop[Px Qy - Py Qx]] =!= 0.,
      Circle[OrthoCentre[{{Px,Py},{Qx,Qy}}],OrthoRadius[{{Px, Py},{Qx, Qy}}],
             OrthoAngles[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]],
      Line[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]]
```

The three functions within are as follows.

```
OrthoCentre[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
   With[{d = 2 Px Qy - 2 Py Qx, p = 1 + Px^2, q = 1 + Qx^2 + Qy^2}, 
      If[N[d] =!= 0.,
         {p Qy + Py^2 Qy - Py q, -p Qx - Py^2 Qx + Px q}/d, 
         ComplexInfinity]]

OrthoRadius[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
   If[N[Chop[Px Qy - Py Qx]] =!= 0., 
      Sqrt[Total[OrthoCentre[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]^2] - 1],
      Infinity]

OrthoAngles[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
   Block[{a, b, c = OrthoCentre[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]},
      If[(a = N[Apply[ArcTan, {Px, Py} - c]]) < 0., a = a + 2 π]; 
      If[(b = N[Apply[ArcTan, {Qx, Qy} - c]]) < 0., 
      b = b + 2 π]; {a, b} = Sort[{a, b}]; 
      If[b - a > π, {b, a + 2 π}, {a, b}]]
```

The Inversion function inverts points, lines, and polygons in a circle.

```
Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_], {Px_, Py_}] := {Cx, Cy} + 
   r^2 {Px - Cx, Py - Cy}/((Cx - Px)^2 + (Cy - Py)^2)
Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], {Px_, Py_}] := {Cx, Cy} + 
   r^2 {Px - Cx, Py - Cy}/((Cx - Px)^2 + (Cy - Py)^2)

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], p_Line] := 
   Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], p_Polygon] := 
   Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Line[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}], {Ux_, Uy_}] := 
   With[{u = Px - Qx, v = Qy - Py},
      {-Ux (v^2 - u^2) - 2 u v Uy, Uy (v^2 - u^2) - 2 u v Ux}/(u^2 + v^2)]
Inversion[Line[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}], p_Polygon] :=
   Map[Inversion[Line[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_], c_List] := 
   Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, c]
```

Invert points of a polygon or list of polygons in a hyperbolic line (which is a line or a circle).

```
PolygonInvert[p_Polygon] := 
   Map[Inversion[HyperbolicLine[#], p] &, 
       Partition[Join[p[[1]], {p[[1, 1]]}], 2, 1]]
PolygonInvert[p_List] := Flatten[Map[PolygonInvert[#] &, p]]
```

Join the points of a hyperbolic polygon with straight or hyperbolic lines.

```
LineRule = Polygon[x_] :> Line[Join[x, {x[[1]]}]];
HyperbolicLineRule = 
   Polygon[x_] :> 
      Map[HyperbolicLine, Partition[Join[x, {x[[1]]}], 2, 1]];
```

The function CentralPolygon finds the initial polygon to begin the iterations. The first point of the polygon (with p sides) is in the first quadrant at angle π/p with respect to the horizontal. Each vertex is surrounded by q such polygons. The polygon may be rotated counter-clockwise through ϕ radians by using the optional third argument.

```
CentralPolygon[p_Integer, q_Integer, ϕ_: 0] := 
   With[{r = (Cot[π/p] Cot[π/q] - 1)/Sqrt[Cot[π/p]^2 Cot[π/q]^2 - 1],
        θ = π Range[1, 2 p - 1, 2]/p}, 
        r Map[{{Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ]}, {Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}}.# &,
             Transpose[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]]]
```

Delete duplicate polygons, allowing a tolerance.

```
PolygonUnion[p_Polygon, tol_: 10.^-10] := p
PolygonUnion[p_List, tol_: 10.^-10] := 
   With[{q = p /. Polygon[x_] :> N[Polygon[Round[x, 10.^-10]]]}, 
        DeleteDuplicates[q]]
```

HyperbolicTessellation tiles polygons with p sides, q of them meeting at each vertex, nesting down to level k. The entire tessellation is rotated counter-clockwise by ϕ radians.

```
HyperbolicTessellation[p_Integer, q_Integer, ϕ_, k_Integer, t_: 10.^-10] := 
   Map[PolygonUnion[#, t] &, 
       NestList[PolygonInvert, Polygon[CentralPolygon[p,q,ϕ]],k][[{-2, -1}]]] /; k > 0

HyperbolicTessellation[p_Integer, q_Integer, ϕ_, k_Integer, t_: 10.^-10] := 
   Polygon[CentralPolygon[p, q, ϕ]] /; k == 0
```

And finally,

```
HyperbolicTessellationGraphics[p_Integer, q_Integer, ϕ_, k_Integer,
      rule_RuleDelayed, opts___] := 
   Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
      HyperbolicTessellation[p, q, ϕ, k, 10.^-10] /. rule}, opts]
```

For example,

```
HyperbolicTessellationGraphics[7, 3, 0., 3, HyperbolicLineRule, PlotLabel -> "{7,3}"]
```

[image: Heptagons, 3 at each vertex]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
   Flatten[HyperbolicTessellation[5,4,0.,4]] /. Polygon[x_] :>
      {ColorData["DarkRainbow", Norm[Mean[x]]], Polygon[x]}}]
```

[image: Pentagons, 4 at each vertex]

```
Block[{poly = Flatten[HyperbolicTessellation[7, 3, 0., 4]]}, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
      poly /. Polygon[x_] :> Polygon[x, VertexColors -> 
       Map[ColorData["SouthwestColors", Norm[#]^1.2 + RandomReal[{0.,0.3}]]&,x]]}]]
```

[image: 7,3 vertex colouring]

And an example of truncation of a heptagon tiling, left as an exercise...

[image: 7,3 truncated]

Comment: This would make for a very nice Demonstration (as in demonstrations.wolfram.com).

Comment: It is a beautiful solution! Is it possible to have non-regular tilings? Like the second figure of OP?